# What does it says about your data and your model if there is not much difference between validation and test data accuracy?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, validation, train

I have modelled (using Adaptive Neuro Fuzzy Inference System) a set of data consisting of 300+ sample points. My data is split into

- 50% training,
- 25% test
- 25% validation.

If there is not much difference between validation and test data accuracy

1. What does it says about your Data?
2. What does it says about your Model?